# Python how to get multiple items from an array?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm attempting to get multiple items from an array but it returns an error however if I get just one it does not.
My code:

```
stockjson = json.loads(stockinfo.text)
test1 = stockjson['variation_list'][0]['test1']
print(test1)
```

Stockinfo:

```
{"id":"TestID","availability_status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","variation_list":[{"sku":"TEST1","availability":0,"availability_status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","test1":"test1"},[{"sku":"TEST2","availability":0,"availability_status":"NOT_AVAILABLE","test1":"test2"},
```

I would like to get the result of every test1 but if I take [0] out of my code I get:

```
    test1 = stockjson['variation_list']['test1']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I'd also like to find the SKU and the test1 for each section (not sure what to call it) thanks for any help provided

Comment: `test1 = [d['test1'] for d in stockjson['variation_list']]` should do it.

Comment: Thanks @YakymPirozhenko, however it prints the full array at the start then after each item in the array is there anyway to stop it printing the full array at the start?

Comment: You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected test data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Comment: You may want to look at using a JSONPath, dpath, KVC, or similar library, that lets you specify things like this with calls like `path(stockjson, 'variation_list.*.test1')`. There are a lot of options, and I don't know which ones to recommend, but you can [search PyPI](https://pypi.org/search/?q=jsonpath), or maybe go to the Community section on python.org and find a mailing list or IRC channel to ask for recommendations on.

Comment: Updated post with another question

Comment: @Ogden Don't do that; create a new question.